# #1062 - Duplicate entry 'default-0-payment/paypal_standard/active' for key 'UNQ_CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH

Tags: mysql, database, magento, paypal

I have [this problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48810/magento-ce-wont-let-me-use-paypal-standard-without-express-which-requires-api) so i followed answer in that link, it didt worked for me.

so i followed comment of @Mukesh Chapagain , `INSERT INTO core_config_data (config_id ,scope ,scope_id ,path ,value) VALUES (NULL , 'default', '0', 'payment/paypal_standard/active', '1' );` but its giving below error :

`#1062 - Duplicate entry 'default-0-payment/paypal_standard/active' for key 'UNQ_CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH`

Comment: It is what the error msg is telling you. The key `UNQ_CORE_CONFIG...` is  complaining that you are duping it up. Do a `show create table core_config_data ` to see that key

Comment: So, right before that call, examine those 5 variables. Look at the relevant table just mentioned. That call already has that key data in it. And your schema says dupes are a no-no for that key.